# Windows 2008 Server SP2 64bit - TCP Connections never releasing after TIME_WAIT

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, 64-bit

We have an issue with Windows 2008 Datacenter edition SP2 64bit. We have a process that is polling very frequently and establishing new TCP connections. The system gets in a state where we end up with over 16k connections in TIME_WAIT state. 
The default OS timeout is 120 seconds after which these connections should go away, but that never happens. These connections persist and never get cleaned up even after the originating process has long terminated (we are still at 16k connections two days after the process was killed). The OS is supposed to time them out but it doesn't.

Has anyone else seen this behavior and if so what was done to resolve it. We are aware of how to tune the tcp stack to make the timeout shorter or allow more connections but this is not the issue here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Amazon EC2 had a major problem with this.  They recently fixed the bug.  Maybe the same problem applies in your situation?

> Hi, I am pasting below an explanation
>   of what was causing this issue. Good
>   news is that this has been fixed very
>   recently by our engineering team. To
>   get fix, all you'll have to do is
>   STOP/START the Windows Server 2008
>   instances where you are seeing this
>   issue. Again, I am not talking about
>   REBOOT which is different. STOP/START
>   causes the instance to move to a
>   different (healthy) host. When these
>   instances launch again, they will be
>   running on hosts that have the fix in
>   place so they won't have this issue
>   again. Now below is the engineering
>   explanation of this issue. After an in
>   depth investigation, we've found that
>   when running Windows 2008 x64 on most
>   available instance types, we've
>   identified an issue which may result
>   in TCP connections that remain in
>   TIME_WAIT/CLOSE_WAIT for excessively
>   long periods of time (in some cases,
>   remaining in this state indefinitely).
>   While in these states, the particular
>   socket pairs remain unusable and if
>   enough accumulate, will result in port
>   exhaustion for the ports in question.
>   If this particular circumstance
>   occurs, the only solution to clear the
>   socket pairs in question is to reboot
>   the instance in question. We have
>   determined the cause to be the values
>   produced by a timer function in
>   Windows 2008 kernel API which, on many
>   of our 64-bit platforms, will
>   occasionally retrieve a value that is
>   extremely far in the future. This
>   affects the TCP stack by causing the
>   timestamps on the TCP socket pairs to
>   be stamped significantly far in the
>   future. According to Microsoft, there
>   is a stored cumulative counter which
>   will not be updated unless the value
>   produced by this API call is larger
>   than the cumulative value. The
>   ultimate result is that sockets
>   created after this point will all be
>   stamped too far in the future until
>   that future time is reached. In some
>   cases, we have seen this value several
>   hundred days into the future, thus the
>   socket pairs appear to be stuck
>   forever.

Comment: Wow great! We have the same problem on EC2, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Microsoft Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx) that describes a few ways to resolve this. It commonly comes from Applications that are badly coded and do not close ports correctly. You need to look at what applications you have installed, or what tasks you are performing and disabling these to see which is causing the issue.

To fix the issue, you want to be looking at either;

1. Increase the upper range of
   ephemeral ports that are dynamically
   allocated to client TCP/IP socket
   connections.
2. Reduce the client
   TCP/IP socket connection timeout
   value from the default value of 240
   seconds (A more permanent fix)

Comment: hyperperforator, that is the common and well-understood manifestation of this problem. The problem that Peco is experiencing (and I as well) is that some time_wait connections are never being released, even after the time_wait delay. Eventually the machine runs out of ports, no matter the rate at which new connections are established.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with windows 2003 server. Problem was solved when I reboot the machine after registry TCPIP parameter change.. May be you can give it a try in server 2008

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this problem differs when the same VM (Windows 2008r2) is deployed on either an Intel or an AMD Magny-Cours VMware server. On the AMD the connections stay in TIME_WAIT indefinately, on the Intel machines they obey the standard 4 mins TIME_WAIT timeout.