# Why is SQL Server using all ephemeral ports connecting to itself and causing TIME_WAITs?

Tags: tcp, netstat, sql-server-2012, time-wait

I've got an AWS server with Windows 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, and Tomcat 7. When I run `netstat -ano` the screen is flooded with `TIME_WAIT`. I posted the [output](https://gist.github.com/jordanbtucker/31e28f831e826fb98c7d) in a Gist.

When I run [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html), filter on port 1433, and turn on Auto Refresh, I can see sqlserver.exe making connections from port 1433 to an ephemeral port and vice versa over and over again.

I've tried researching why this is happening, but it's always a dead end. Does anyone know why?

**PS**

[An answer regarding an AWS bug](https://serverfault.com/a/255701/82866) seemed to be promising, but it's from 2011, and they were experiencing a different issue. The connections on my sever are eventually closing. I just don't know why they're getting opened so frequently.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?